# How to overload assignment operator and create copy constructor for 2D Dynamic Arrays?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, dynamic, 2d

I have a flight class which has bool** property in it.

```
class Flight {
public:
 int flightNumber;
 int row;
 int seat;
 bool** seatReserv;
 Flight();
 Flight(int fly,int rw,int st);
 ~Flight();
 Flight(const Flight& rightVal);
 Flight& operator=(const Flight& rightVal);
 };
```

I tried to write my overloaded assignment operator as below, however i realised that even i change my row and seat property, i am not changing the 2D arrays [row] and [seat] size.

```
Flight& Flight::operator=(const Flight& rightVal){
        if(this != &rightVal){
                for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
                    delete[] this->seatReserv[i];
                }
                delete [] this->seatReserv;


            flightNumber = rightVal.flightNumber;
            row = rightVal.row;
            seat = rightVal.seat;



            this -> seatReserv = new bool*[row];
            for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
                seatReserv[i] = new bool[seat];

            }

            for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < seat; j++){
                    seatReserv[i][j] = rightVal.seatReserv[i][j];

                }
            }


        }

        return *this;

        }
```

Furthemore i encountered the same problem in my copy constructor below, so the question is how can i write copy constructor and overload my assignment operator for my class?

```
Flight::Flight(const Flight& rightVal){
        flightNumber = rightVal.flightNumber;
        row = rightVal.row;
        seat = rightVal.seat;
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < seat; j++){
                seatReserv[i][j] = rightVal.seatReserv[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT:I can not use vectors this is for a homework assignment so vector using is forbidden.

Comment: Just a remark, a double pointer is **not** the same thing as a 2D array. It only point to an array or pointers which is quite a different animal of a 2D array. In the latter rows are contiguous while it is not required in the former.

Comment: This `delete[] this->seatReserv[seat];` in your first `for` loop smells funny! I think you mean `delete[] this->seatReserv[i];`.

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` might help (even if it might be a special specialization).

Comment: *"I can not use vectors"*, So write your own (simplified) version.

Comment: Then ideally, special members of `Flight` might be defaulted :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would probably work as copy constructor:

```
Flight::Flight(const Flight &rightVal){
    this->flightNumber = rightVal.flightNumber;
    this->row = rightVal.row;
    this->seat = rightVal.seat;
    this->seatReserv = new bool*[row];
    for (int i = 0; i < this->row; i++){
        this->seatReserv[i] = new bool[seat];
        for (int j = 0; j < this->seat; j++){
            this->seatReserv[i][j] = rightVal.seatReserv[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

For the = operator you could probably use the same thing as above, but don't forget to delete what was there before using the destructor (this is to avoid memory leaks).

```
Flight::~Flight(){
    if (seatReserv == nullptr) return; //this means that at the beginning of the class seatReserv should be set to nullptr.

    for (int i = 0; i < this->row; i++){
        delete[] seatReserv[i];
    }
    delete[] seatReserv;
}
```

I also suggest that instead of using a "2D array", you use one single sequence of bools, with length `row * seat`. To access one at a specific place you'd do this:
`i * row + j`, instead of this `array[i][j]`.

This is faster when allocating and freeing and it's more efficient for your CPU cache.

Comment: `this->seatReserv = new bool*[row];` I think in this line there is a memory leak because seatReserv pointer to pointer has a reference when we assign it to new one, wont we lose the previous memory?

Comment: That's only if was pointing to something else before, that's why with the = operator you have to use the destructor, before copying.

Comment: Unless you plan to use the copy constructor after having already done things, with the instance. In  which case there will be a memory leak, but who uses a constructor after the object already exists.

Comment: what is the problem in my current assignment operator?

Comment: Maybe in the beginning. You are deleting without checking if there is anything there, which results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: When i cout as "Test1","Test2" etc inside the for loops in my copy constructor and assignment operator i can not see any cout results, i think my code does not going inside in for loops that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

This

```
       this -> seatReserv = new bool*[row];
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
            seatReserv[i] = new bool[i];

        }
```

should be this

```
       this -> seatReserv = new bool*[row];
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
            seatReserv[i] = new bool[seat];

        }
```

The little details matter.

Your copy constructor doesn't allocate any memory for your 2D array, so that's a problem.

Comment: Should i write this or can i call seatReserv as seatReserv without using this pointer does it matters?

Comment: does my copy constructor and assignment operator correct now ?

Comment: Just test it I'd say.